# Reduce System of 3 ODEs to 2 ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, nonlinear-dynamics

I'm currently self-studying the book "Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos". I got the following system

$$
\dot{x} = -kxy \\
\dot{y} = kxy - ly \\
\dot{z} = ly
$$

According to a comment on one of Strogatzs' videos on Youtube one is able to reduce this system to 2 equations. I never did something along the lines so I'm not quite sure how to do this. $\dot{y}$ looks like a combination of the other two. Can I simply say something along the lines that $\dot{y}$ is equal to $-(\dot{x} - \dot{z})$ and simply apply the methods I already know to to $\dot{x}$ and $\dot{z}$?

In the book is an exercise where they combine the system to a single ODE, but I don't really get how as well. I assume combining it to two ODEs must be simpler.

I would appreciate some help or some resource I can check out to understand the process better.

Comment: Although I don't know what the author has done in the book nor their intentions, that is exactly how you would go about reducing the number of ODEs, by removing the ODE for $y$; realise it is equal to $-(\dot{x} + \dot{z})$, integrate to get $y = - (x + z) + C$ and then substitute this result into the ODEs for $x, z$. Finally, from this result above, you can just see directly that $$\dot{x} + \dot{y} + \dot{z} = 0$$ which reduces the system to a single ODE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\dot{x} = -kxy \\
\dot{y} = kxy - ly \\
\dot{z} = ly$$
Add all the DE:
$$\dfrac {d}{dt}(x+y+z)=0$$
$$x+y+z=C$$

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the 2 first equations for $x,y,$ and then $z=-x-y+C.$